# Why does "someString" == 0 evaluate to true in PHP

Tags: php

I'm a little bit confused about `truth` in PHP.

My understanding is that 0 evaluates to false, and non-empty strings (unless the string is "0") evaluate to true.

This is as I expect:

```
var_dump((bool) 0);              // prints "boolean false"
var_dump((bool) 'someString');   // prints "boolean true"
```

But then I am surprised by the following result:

```
var_dump((0=='someString'));     // prints "boolean true"
```

My question is, why does `0=='someString'` evaluate to true?

Comment: Nanne - I understand the difference between those operators. This is a question about how true/false is evaluated in `==` comparisons of different types. Different IMO.

Comment: php is a soft typing language, it converts types on the fly 0 can be both a string and an integer depending on where its used with no changes made

Comment: Error in your title."someString" == 0 does NOT evaluate to true since it's a string compare, but 0=="somestring " does since it is a numeric compare.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using the comparison (`==`) operator strings will be converted to an integer when compared to another integer. This is because of [type juggling in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php). So  `"someString"` evaluates to zero because it is converted to an integer and has no leading digits. If you use the the identical operator (`===`) type conversions are not done so `"someString"` is treated a literal string and your statement will then evaluate to false.

The following will evaluate to false when type juggling is performed. Everything else will be evaluated as true:

- "" (an empty string)
- 0 (0 as an integer)
- 0.0 (0 as a float)
- "0" (0 as a string)
- NULL
- FALSE
- array() (an empty array)
- $var; (a variable declared, but without a value)

Comment: This is about conversion to integers, not to booleans.

Comment: `==` does convert to integers, that's the whole point of this answer.

Comment: The conversion to integers is the reason for the boolean result.